# GET в решетке и получение данных

Tags: php, javascript

Имеется множество url вида 
http://site.ru/site.html#id=test
http://site.ru/site.html#id=test2
http://site.ru/site.html#id=test3
http://site.ru/site.html#id=test4
Как по мере выбранного url получать значение test?
Пытался средствами GET но метод не определяет значения id

Comment: Посмотрите запросы в логах `apache` - на сервер такие запросы приходят без данных после решетки. Т.е. получить такие данные нельзя. Решетка используется только на `html` страницах.

Comment: Можно поменять URL на `http://site.ru/site.html?id=test`, после чего получать GET-параметр `id` в PHP.

Answer (score 8):

Значения после # не отправляются на сервер. Их можно получить только на стороне клиента средствами JavaScript. Оно находится в location.hash. Если необходимо получать контент с сервера в зависимости от хеша — необходимо использовать ajax.

Comment: Можете показать пример запроса в бд средствами аякса? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Суть ajax отправить данные на сервер не перезагружая страницу. Запрос к БД будет таким же как и в остальных местах. Можете почитать подробнее здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-intro

Comment: Только вот не `location.hash()`, а `location.hash`.