# Получить url с флагом в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel5

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с задачей, в которой нужно получить полную строку get с флагом.
Пример того что нужно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions#flag
Пробовал использовать:

```
 Request::fullUrl(),Request::getQueryString(),Request::getPathInfo(),URL::full(),
```

но так и не получил нужного результата строки с флагом.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448986/get-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: Этот хеш используется только на фронте, посмотрите что прийдет на сервер в GET запросе на такой адрес - там его не будет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [GET в решетке и получение данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448986/get-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)